# element blocks hover effect of other elements

Tags: html, css, hover

I have two elements, a circle and a square (2 different div). The square is on top of the circle, but it **blocks the hover effect of the element underneath** (the circle turns blue, for example).
Applying the hover effect to the square doesn't work, because the hover effect applies to every part of the circle.

In the real example (see second image), you can see that the circle is **divided with the skew and rotate transformation**.

I don't want to use JavaScript, just CSS and HTML.

---

I simplified the problem in this CodePen: codepen.io/tuurtie/pen/XWYPWEb.

[image]

This is an image of the actual result (red is what blocks the hover effect of the circle):
[image]

I have played around with the overflow of both, and I have tried to make a hole in the square, but this still blocks the hover. I know I'm close!

I also added a hover effect to the red square itself, but then the hover effect doesn't work (the hover effect applies to every part of the circle).

Comment: did you try `pointer-events: none` for the square to make it opaque to mouse interaction?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>`) to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IT goldman said, you could use `pointer-events: none;`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.circle:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.square {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>The hover effect of the black circle doesn't work when you go over the red square.</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

**However, this will disable any pointer events you want to apply to the square.** Another solution could use a bit of JavaScript:

```js
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
const square = document.querySelector(".square");

square.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
  circle.classList.add("circle-on-hover");
})

square.addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => {
  circle.classList.remove("circle-on-hover");
})
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}


/*  create a class that can be added
to the circle when square is hovered over */

.circle:hover,
.circle-on-hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}


/*  demonstrates that the square still
receives pointer events */

.square:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>The hover effect of the black circle doesn't work when you go over the red square.</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

But you *did* specify you didn't want any JS mixed in. I don't think there are any other CSS-only solutions that enable the type of behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! It already had the idea to use JavaScript onclick, but I didn't want to make my explanation more complicated :). Your answer is perfect! I knew that I was missing just 1 little line ;).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in your markup. Even though the styling displayed the Square inside of the Circle, the markup had them next to each other in the `DOM`.

What I did was place the square inside of the circle and style the circle accordingly with `flex box` to place the square in the middle.

https://codepen.io/gezzasa/pen/xxzabEL

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! It did indeed solve the problem, but it didn't work in my actual project, so it's my fault :). (I did try your answer before I posted this question). Your answer deserves a vote!